# Beneficio do uso de engine de templates

Tags: javascript, template, handlebars.js

Eu estou criando células para tabelas pegando informações de uma api usando "append", eu gostaria de saber se existiria algum beneficio em usar alguma engine de template como Handlebars.js em vez de usar "append"?

código:

```
function ajaxRank(){
  var $orders = $('#orders');


  $.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': '69e49cf35c7346fcb819f023cf0b98d4' },
    url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398/leagueTable',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
  }).done(function(response) {
    var regex = /.*?$/;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      $('#tbodyRank').append('<tr>' + '<td>' + response.standing[i].position + '</td>'
      +'<td><img id="logo" src="../style/img/' + response.standing[i].teamName +'.png"' +  'alt="description here" /></td>'
       + '<td>' + response.standing[i].teamName + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + response.standing[i].playedGames + '</td>'+
      '<td>' + response.standing[i].points + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + response.standing[i].goals + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + response.standing[i].goalsAgainst + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + response.standing[i].goalDifference + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + response.standing[i].wins + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + response.standing[i].draws + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + response.standing[i].losses + '</td>' + '</tr>' );
    }
  });
}


module.exports = ajaxRank;
```

Answer (score 4):

A sua pergunta é muito relativa pois tanto faz na realidade, é uma questão de gosto (e de opinião) a diferença está mesmo é na **qualidade** e na **organização** que você deseja para o seu código.

### Arquitetura da Aplicação & Hierarquia de Informação

Não faço ideia de como é o funcionamento da sua aplicação por tanto não posso diagnosticar se é melhor ou não pra você usar o `handlebars.js`, porém aqui vão algumas perguntas que você deveria se fazer, para só então, avaliar se é viável a utilização de algum **Template Engine**:

- Você está seguindo algum **Framework**? Se a sua resposta é SIM, dê uma olhada na documentação do mesmo e veja como a *comunidade* organizou o projeto.

Se fossemos seguir um exemplo que provavelmente não se aplica nesse caso mas é bom para conhecimento, temos o famoso **Laravel Framework**, que é um *Framework PHP* baseado n Padrão de Arquitetura MVC, do qual resumidamente, separa a aplicação em camadas tendo o:

- **Model** - Responsável por interagir diretamente com a *Base de Dados* trabalhando com as tabelas, as colunas e etc...
- **View** - O *View* nada mais é o que nós (usuários) vemos e interagimos na página que seria equivalente hoje ao *HTML, CSS e JavaScript*.
- **Controller** - Faz o intermédio entre a *View* e a *Model*, é no *Controller* que você faz a verificação, sanitização dos *inputs*, é lá onde é definido para qual *Model* os dados serão repassados e etc...

Leia mais sobre o Padrão de Arquitetura **Model-View-Controller** acessando o link a seguir http://blog.thiagobelem.net/o-que-e-o-mvc.

- Você acha que usando o `handlebars.js` deixará seu código mais legível e de fácil manutenabilidade?
- Tal dependência é fácil de ser implementada no projeto, sem muitas (ou nenhuma) dor de cabeça?

### Conclusão

Na minha opinião um bom desenvolvedor não só sabe "codar" muito bem ou manjar muito de alguma linguagem de programação seja Front-end ou Back-end. Mas um bom desenvolvedor sabe o que é melhor para o seu projeto/aplicação sendo imparcial e não favorecendo alguma tecnologia só porque ele acha (apenas por achar) que é o melhor.

Se eu vir aqui e te dizer que é melhor você usar o `handlebars.js` eu estaria mentindo, assim como se eu também te falasse o contrário.

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil pra você, ficaria feliz se pudesse marcar ela como a correta.